# Begins with Coding or UML modeling

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

From a SharePoint developer's experiencce, when you retrieve the requirement specification, do you started doing a UML modeling or start coding in Visual Studio?

The goal, from my side is to understand, what is the recommended approach to develop a good SP project.

Comment: Since this question does not have an absolute right or wrong, and the answers will be very based on personal preferences and experience, I have converted it to a wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my perspective, I try to use the [no-code-solution](/questions/tagged/no-code-solution) approach first. Asking "What can we do with out-of-the-box-SharePoint" is my recommendation. Not only does it make you understand the anotomy of SharePoint, but it makes your life easier as well. I've seen numerous of implementations where custom web parts have been developed where there exist OOTB web parts doing the exact same thing.

When all of your OOTB options are out, then you start drawing your UML diagram, Balsamiq mockups and create a new empty SharePoint project in Visual Studio.

Comment: 100% agree, assess what you have "for free". After that, model what you don't, then create in VS.

Comment: "What can we do with out-of-the-box-SharePoint"? Can you provide some real-based example?

Comment: @FullMetalGame Today I was asked to implement a user story: "Users want to filter on images in the horizontal navigation above the search results" which could be implemented through code, but I managed to find an out-of-the-box-solution adding an imageresult.aspx, a result source (Images), edit the search navigation web part implementing the new query based on my Images result source. 2 hours instead of 2 days :-)

Comment: I understand. Another question is. Is it possible advance the current functionality of SP:s OOTB:s functionality? I don't want to create it from scratch, just advance the functionality.

Comment: @FullMetalGame Sure. One example is the [Content Enrichment Web Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2013/06/19/advanced-content-enrichment-in-sharepoint-2013-search.aspx) where you can add functionality to excisting search topology. Nice if you want to add metadata to file share content crawl.

Comment: Is there a list in table at Internet to find out available and current functionality of SP:s OOTB:s?

Answer (score 0):

this is relative with size of your project.

I use my method of UML

I begin for Visio document to understand all the process, after I validate the Visio Document with users, I begin the development.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is for using requirements & modeling approaches especially for enterprise solutions that can get quite complex. 'Use Cases' is a great way to document the requirements and confirm the specifications. To get you started, there's a nice presentation about using [UML for SharePoint 2010 here...](http://prezi.com/t_mk-gs_lvh4/uml-for-sharepoint-2010/)